# Getting the Value from ExtractQuarter

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django model. When the form to populate this model is completed, I want my save function to use the new ExtractQuarter database function on one of the fields input by the user. Based on the value produced by ExtractQuarter, I want to populate another field which is hidden from the form's user.

However, I cannot figure out how to actually get the value from ExtractQuarter.

The save function is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    q = ExtractQuarter(self.fiscal_year_end).values.get()
    if q >= 3:
        y = ExtractYear(self.fiscal_year_end).Value()
    else:
        y = ExtractYear(self.fiscal_year_end).Value()-1
    self.fiscal_year = y
    super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This gives me:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'ExtractQuarter' and 'int'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `ExtractQuarter` is *not* meant to function on values, it is used to compose a query. There is no *Python* logic in the operator to let it work with "ordinary" Python values.

Comment: Furthermore I get another error `ExtractQuarter` has no attribute `.values`. Are you sure the error is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I cannot figure out how to actually get the value from `ExtractQuarter`.

You *can't*. Most *tranformers* (including `ExtractQuarter`), have no real *semantical* logic attached to it.This will write a query such that instead of writing `SELECT foo FROM bar`, the query now reads `SELECT QUARTER(foo) FROM bar`. But you can not use this at the Python/Django level to convert `datetime` (or related) objects into a quarter.

We can however "mimic" the behavior. If we for example take a look at the definition of the [`QUARTER` function](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/quarter.php), we see:

> The `QUARTER` function returns the quarter (a number from `1` to `4`)
>   given a date value.
>
> - Dates that have a month of Jan-Mar would return `1`.
> - Dates that have a month of Apr-Jun would return `2`.
> - Dates that have a month of Jul-Sep would return `3`.
> - Dates that have a month of Oct-Dec would return `4`.

We can thus define such function ourselve like:

```py
def obtain_quarter(dt):
    if dt is not None:
        return (2 + dt.month) // 3

def obtain_year(dt):
    if dt is not None:
        return dt.year
```

So then you can use it like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    q = obtain_quarter(self.fiscal_year_end)
    self.fiscal_year = obtain_year(self.fiscal_year_end) - (q < 3)
    super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the **`fiscal_year_end`** field is a python's [DateTime object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html), you will get the quarter by,

```
import math


class Mymodel(models.Model):
    # your fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        quarter = math.ceil(self.fiscal_year_end.month / 3)
        if quarter >= 3:
            self.fiscal_year = self.fiscal_year_end.year
        else:
            self.fiscal_year = self.fiscal_year_end - 1
        super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```